# How to get the last work day in SQL Server date dimension?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We are using a dimension table for dates based [on this blog post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/).
There is a view which gives for each date if it is a week day/ weekend or if that date is a holiday.

| TheDate | IsWeekend | IsHoliday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-13 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-04-14 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-04-15 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-04-16 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-04-17 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-04-18 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-04-19 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-04-20 | 0 | 0 |

We are using a window function with with LAG() to get the last workday on weekends:

```
SELECT [TheDate]
    ,[TheDayName]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN [TheDayOfWeek] = 1
            THEN LAG([TheDate], 2) OVER (
                    ORDER BY [TheDate]
                    )
        WHEN [TheDayOfWeek] = 2
            THEN LAG([TheDate], 3) OVER (
                    ORDER BY [TheDate]
                    )
        ELSE LAG([TheDate], 1) OVER (
                ORDER BY [TheDate]
                )
        END AS LastWorkDay
FROM [dbo].[TheCalendar]
```

The result is as expected:

| TheDate | TheDayName | LastWorkDay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-13 | Wednesday | 2022-04-12 |
| 2022-04-14 | Thursday | 2022-04-13 |
| 2022-04-15 | Friday | 2022-04-14 |
| 2022-04-16 | Saturday | 2022-04-15 |
| 2022-04-17 | Sunday | 2022-04-15 |
| 2022-04-18 | Monday | 2022-04-15 |
| 2022-04-19 | Tuesday | 2022-04-18 |

I am looking now how the window function can include holidays, so the Workday before Tuesday, April 19 is actually Thursday, April 15 because Monday (4/16) and Friday (4/15) are holidays and Sunday (4/17) and Saturday (4/16) are Weekend (Well Sunday in fact is both).
I tried to use a cursor to iterate dates down to the next work day but it is everything than performant. I am thinking now to materialize the last workday for weekends and then again doing the same exercise for holidays.
What could be a more intelligent approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lptr commented, you can use max...over query to acheive the requirement. Made few changes in that query to work for all use cases. Below is the query.

**Query:**

```
select *, case when IsWeekend=0 and IsHoliday=0 then lag(TheDate,1) over (order by TheDate) else
  max(case when IsWeekend=0 and IsHoliday=0 then theDate end) 
  over(order by TheDate rows between 10 preceding and 1 preceding) end
  from [dbo].[TheCalendar]
```

This query selects all columns from the table `TheCalendar` and uses a `CASE` statement to check if the current date is a weekend or holiday. If it is not, then it uses the `LAG` function to get the previous non-holiday and non-weekend date. If it is a weekend or holiday, then it uses a window function to get the maximum date for the previous 10 non-holiday and non-weekend days. The query you provided is correct.

**Input:**

| TheDate | IsWeekend | IsHoliday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-13 | False | False |
| 2022-04-14 | False | False |
| 2022-04-15 | False | True |
| 2022-04-16 | True | False |
| 2022-04-17 | True | True |
| 2022-04-18 | False | True |
| 2022-04-19 | False | False |
| 2022-04-20 | False | False |

**Output:**

| TheDate | IsWeekend | IsHoliday | PrevDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-13 | False | False | null |
| 2022-04-14 | False | False | 2022-04-13 |
| 2022-04-15 | False | True | 2022-04-14 |
| 2022-04-16 | True | False | 2022-04-14 |
| 2022-04-17 | True | True | 2022-04-14 |
| 2022-04-18 | False | True | 2022-04-14 |
| 2022-04-19 | False | False | 2022-04-18 |
| 2022-04-20 | False | False | 2022-04-19 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F-5MC7qr)

Comment: Lag is not required at all.

Comment: The right hint came from @lptr, but since this was a comment and you build it into your answer, I check this as the right answer. Thanks all